# Sort Numerically Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array with objects, and I want to sort them by name :

```js
myArray = [{name: 'name10'}, {name: 'name9'}, {name: 'name1'}, {name: 'name3'}]
```

When I apply the sort method like this

```js
myArray.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0));
```

it gives me 10 just after 1

```
myArray = [{name: 'name1'}, {name: 'name10'}, {name: 'name3'}, {name: 'name9'}]
```

Can I fix this ?

Comment: Your "1" should be "01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the names by the number at the end:

```js
myArray = [{name: 'name10'}, {name: 'name9'}, {name: 'name1'}, {name: 'name3'}]
myArray.sort((a,b) => {
     let aNumber = a.name.match(/\d+$/), bNumber = b.name.match(/\d+$/);
     if(aNumber && bNumber)
          return parseInt(aNumber[0]) - parseInt(bNumber[0]);
     else
          return a-b;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Undervoter, you need to explain...

Comment: why it has been downvoted?

Comment: @MajedBadawi try putting one of the  fields to "name" only . it will respond with error

Comment: @yash can see above comment.

Comment: @MajedBadawi you don't need `[0]`

Comment: That's works Thx

Comment: @AjeetEppakayala I updated the answer, thanks for the comment

Comment: @Seb You are welcome.

Comment: @MajedBadawi this still won't work with one of the fields as {name: "name"}

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with options.

```js
const array = [{ name: 'name10' }, { name: 'name9' }, { name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name3' }];

array.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) =>
    a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' })
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a great solution